# Google tango calibration tool

Tags: google-project-tango

I am trying to install Tango calibration tool (TangoAdjuster.apk) but it is failed with error:
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY]

Does anybody has the same issue?